# Azure account vs subscription

Tags: azure

I'm in the process of moving a azure subscription from one Azure AD into another Azure AD.
Before I could do that I have to create a new Azure Account for the target Azure AD.

I assumed that a subscription and account was the same, but it's not.

1. How does an Azure account and an azure subscription relate to each other?
2. How does billing profiles relate to subscriptions and azure accounts?

Do these relate one to many or one to one?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Account sits on an Azure Active Directory(AAD). It is a just an email (identity) which allows you to access the resources linked with all the subscriptions linked with the AAD with proper permissions of-course.

**Azure Subscription** : An Azure subscription is a base container that comprises a group of related business or technical resources. The group of resources are used and billed together. An Azure subscription also acts as an administrative boundary, meaning that it allows subscription administrators to access all resources within the subscription and delegate access through role-based access-control mechanisms.

**Billing is directly linked with the subscription.**
Subscription is billed based on the billing profile.
Normal Users (Azure Accounts) are not billed individually unless Subscription Admin decides a method for them.

**Billing profile** : A billing profile contains a payment method, Bill-to information, and other invoice settings, such as purchase order number and email invoice preference.

So multiple subscriptions can be charged with single billing profile or the Subscription admin can use different profiles for different subscription.

References-

What is Azure Active Directory:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-whatis

The relationship between AAD and subscriptions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associate...

Managing resource groups with AAD:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-manage-groups

Understanding billing profile:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/commerce/billing-and-payments/manage-billing-profiles?view=o365-worldwide

Comment: When you say it's just an email, do you mean like a user under AAD? Because in this situation that already existed, I was logged in as the AAD user inside the azure portal. I though a user account under AAD was a "Azure Account" but according to support, an "Azure account" was some administrative infromation about my business, not something I could login as. They told me to "register an azure account using the same email as the AAD user account".

Comment: AAD is created with the user who creates the account. Later accounts are added in the AD. In your case may be the MS guy is asking to login with the user who created the account. But, still owner, admin and user all are part of AAD